# oracle spool query

Tags: oracle, spool

I have written the sql by name **cashload.txt** on unix box and kept it on the following location on unix box:

```
exit |sqlplus -s batch/password@SW_TEST @/soft/checkfree/AccurateBXG/scripts/cashload.txt
```

In the cashload.txt the below code is written:

```
spool /Detail/reports/inner/SW/Rep_OIbyAccount_$DATE_FILE.csv
select accountnumber||','||accountname||','||X from HSBC_Cash_OIbyAccount_v;
spool off
```

But it is not spooling the result set on the above mentioned path.However,when I am giving the path where the script is kept,It is spooling at that location.I don't understand why?It is spooling at the below path where the **cashload.txt**(sql script) is kept:

```
**spool /soft/checkfree/AccurateNXG/scripts/Rep_OIbyAccount.csv**
select accountnumber||','||accountname||','||X from HSBC_Cash_OIbyAccount_v;
spool off
```

Please look into the above query and help me out.
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: It is bad practice to use the .txt extension for a SQL script. Anybody else looking at your files would expect executable SQL to be in a script with a .sql extension.  Only non-executable ASCII files should be given a .txt extension.

Comment: What happens when you:

1) from the command prompt issue the command " touch Detail/reports/inner/SW/Rep_OIbyAccount_TEST.csv"  

2) eliminate the $DATE_FILE shell variable from the spool file name, for example "spool /Detail/reports/inner/SW/Rep_OIbyAccount_TEST.csv"

?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly, DATE_FILE is a shell variable that you want to substitute into the spool file name.  This might be part or all of your problem.  I don't think you can reference this directly from SQLPlus.  You would need to pass that in as a parameter to the script then reference it as a SQLPlus substitution variable.

So the command line would be:

```
sqlplus -s batch/password@SW_TEST @/soft/checkfree/AccurateBXG/scripts/cashload.txt $DATE_FILE
```

And the spool command in the script would be:

```
spool /Detail/reports/inner/SW/Rep_OIbyAccount_&1..csv
```

(The extra period is necessary because it serves as a terminator to the substition variable name.)

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly it is a file permissions problem.  Remember that when we interact with the OS from inside the database we are using the oracle account, not the account we connected as.

So does the oracle account have write permissions on /Detail/reports/inner ?

Comment: Since this is spooling from the SQLPlus client, the question is actually whether the user account running SQLPlus has write permission to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Can you echo the value of "/Detail/reports/inner/SW/Rep_OIbyAccount_$DATE_FILE.csv" ?

Only reason I can think of are 
 a) The above location is not a valid path 
 b) You do not have permissions to write to that location.

Do you get an error in the first case, or does nothing happen at all ?

Comment: I am not getting any error in the first case,overall nothing happens.Any idea??

Comment: Did you check if you have permissions as suggested by APC ? How about doing a chmod and chown on the directory "detail/reports/inner/sw" for the oracle account ? Did you try that ?

Answer (score 0):

Does running without the silent (-s) option give you any more detail?

Comment: no,nothing is displayed...It is connecting the session and after completing the task it get disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

The path mentioned by you has a `$` symbol which is causing the problem. To avoid that just give the path and file name in `" "`. That should solve the problem:

```
SPOOL "/Detail/reports/inner/SW/Rep_OIbyAccount_$DATE_FILE.csv "
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the following to see if it generats the desired output. It will put in the directory which you are currently in.

```
set termout  off
set echo     off
set linesize 140
set feedback off
set pagesize 0

spool DATE_FILE.csv
select accountnumber
       ||','
       ||accountname
       ||','
       || X 
  from HSBC_Cash_OIbyAccount_v;
spool off
ed DATE_FILE.csv
```